# Unable to resolve module fs when running expo start

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, expo

Can't for the life of me figure out why my app suddenly won't start. I keep getting this error:

> Unable to resolve module fs from
> `node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js`: fs could not
> be found within the project.
> If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
>
> 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
> 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
> 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
> 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

whenever I run `expo start` in the root folder. I've even tried `expo start -c` to reset the cache.

I've also tried removing node_modules and npm installing it back for both the {myapp}/functions/node_modules and {myapp}/node_modules.

I've tried updating firebase-admin and all dependencies.

It's weird because my app was working a couple days ago and this came out of the blue. I've never had to install fs before.

Anyone got any idea what's going on here? It feels like a simple environment fix, but I'm not sure.

My app dependencies if it helps:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "expo": "^41.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~10.1.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.11.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.6.0",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^6.3.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.9.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^41.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "./node_modules/(?!(react-navigation-header-buttons|react-native|react-native-gesture-handler|@expo)|expo-font|@unimodules|expo-asset|expo-constants|expo-file-system|expo-web-browser|react-navigation|react-navigation-stack|unimodules-permissions-interface|expo-permissions|expo-image-picker|expo-linear-gradient/)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "updateSnapshot": true
  }
}
```

and `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "babel-preset-expo"
    ]
}
```

and firebase functions dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^4.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.23.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^8.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

firebase-admin is then intialized in my {myapp}/functions/index.js as:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
```

and then used as (for example):

```
// Called for toggling Tutorial Prompt on ProfileScreen
exports.setTutorialPrompt = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

    res.status(201).send("CORS preflight options set!");
  } else {
    const db = admin.firestore(); // <--------------------------- here
    const { exampleId, ExampletwoId, value, screen } = req.body;

    const updatedProfile = {
      tutorialPrompt: value,
    };

    const index = await client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);

    index
      .partialUpdateObject({
        objectID: ExhibitUId,
        tutorialPrompt: value,
      })
      .wait();

    db.collection("users").doc(localId).update(updatedProfile);

    res.status(201).send(`Successfully toggled tutorialing prompt`);
  }
});
```

Comment: `fs` is a node standard library module, it is not available in the react-native environment just like it is not available in a web browser. the library you are trying to use is meant for use in node.js.

Comment: It's used in a node.js environment. The firebase-admin library is used in {myapp}/functions, where I use node.js to communicate with firebase cloud functions. Thanks for pointing that out though, I'll edit my post to show that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

It was a random import error within the root app folder. Somehow one of my imports got mixed up, and was trying to call a cloud function instead of a redux-action function.

The wrong import:

```
import { setTutorialPrompt } from "../../functions/index.js";
```

The correct import:

```
import { setTutorialPrompt } from "../../store/actions/user";
```

Since it was trying to import my functions folder, it gave me the fs error. Similar to what @brentvatne was talking about.

If anyone else runs into this error, I recommend moving your cloud functions folder to your desktop or something, and try running your app without it. That's how I found the right error code.

Answer (score 1):

I found this because I ran into pretty much exactly this same issue.

I discovered that there are (weirdly) two ways you can import `firebase-admin` into react native projects. I was doing `import { firestore } from "firebase-admin"` and I needed to be doing `import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'`

A pretty easy-to-miss difference, so I thought I’d leave a comment here in case anyone else has this issue.